# Check if user type a single character or number in textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I already can make the login for user, so if user type their username or password wrongly in textbox, the message label that says "**Invalid username or password**" appear. But, i want to when user type a single character or number in textbox when the message label is appear, the message label will not visible to user (`visible = false`) as user already type a single character or number in textbox. But the message label didn't disappear when user type a single character or number.

This is the code:

```
private void CheckTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
            {
                label5.Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                label5.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

And here is the image:

Below image is when user type wrongly (the username or password), the message label appear:

[image]

Below image is when user type a single character or number, but the message label still at there

[image]

My question is: How do i set the message label to not show when user type a single character or number in the textbox?

Any help?

Your answer will be great appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You need to make sure this `CheckTextBox` method is wired up to the `TextChanged` event of the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You have not wiredup the `CheckTextBox()` method for both `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` `TextChanged` Event.

**Solution :** in your Form_Load WireUp the `CheckTextBox()` method for the `Textbox1` and `TextBox2` TextChanged Event as below:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.CheckTextBox);
      textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.CheckTextBox);
    }
```

**Suggestion :** i think `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is more appropriate as it would also check for `Whitespace` in addition to `null` and `Empty` strings.

Try This:

```
   private void CheckTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
        {
            label5.Visible = true;
        }

        else
        {
            label5.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is checking if either textbox has information in it.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
```

Change the `||` to `&&` and then the label will only be shown when BOTH textboxes do not have any data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
private void CheckTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
     {
         label5.Visible = true;
     }

     else
     {
         label5.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

If you change `||` to `&&` then `label5` will be visible only if **both** textboxes are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code, **Should be call this OnTextChanged="CheckTextBox" on your textbox**

```
protected void CheckTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
            {
                label5.Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                label5.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

---

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="CheckTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
```

---

Try this..use && instead of ||

```
private void CheckTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
     {
         label5.Visible = true;
     }

     else
     {
         label5.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Kaoru sir Glad i cound help